# Can't tell left() from right() in R

Tags: r

Are R's `gdata::left()` and `gdata::right()` actually the same functions, but with different names and working exactly as they should, or am I using them incorrectly?

I have: `mtcars`

I want:  only the last 2 columns from `mtcars`

(I know I could ask for this with `mtcars[,(length(mtcars)-1):(length(mtcars))]`, but why would I if there is an easier way?)

What I want looks like this:

```
                    gear carb
Mazda RX4              4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag          4    4
Datsun 710             4    1
Hornet 4 Drive         3    1
Hornet Sportabout      3    2
...
```

It seems like `right(mtcars,2)` would accomplish this, but instead it gives

```
                     mpg cyl
Mazda RX4           21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6
Datsun 710          22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8
...
```

Which is exactly the same as `left(mtcars,2)`:

```
                     mpg cyl
Mazda RX4           21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6
Datsun 710          22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8
...
```

My main question is, **what is the simplest way to get the rightmost n columns from a dataframe?** I want something, hopefully base R, that doesn't require knowing the number of total number of columns of `mtcars`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `tail` on the column names from `base R` to get the last `n` columns

```
mtcars[tail(names(mtcars), 2)]
```

Or `head` to get the first `n` columns

```
mtcars(head(names(mtcars), 2)]
```

Comment: How can this be used when dfs without names? e.g. `names(volcano)` returns `NULL`?

Comment: @Anomie  IN that case, do `mtcars[tail(seq_along(mtcars), 2)]` or if it is a matrix, the `volcano` is not a data.frame, `volcano[, tail(seq_len(ncol(volcano)), 2)]`

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be a weird/silly bug in gdata. If you look at the source for [left/right](https://rdrr.io/cran/gdata/src/R/left.R) you will see that both functions get a `UseMethod("left")`. As far as I understand, that means that calls for either with a data.frame, will result in a call to `left.data.frame`. Indeed, if I type in

```
right <- function(x, n=6L) UseMethod("right")
```

then `right(mtcars,2)` works as expected.

Comment: Nice work digging into the source of the issue, @iod. You can submit this as a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/warnes/gdata/issues

Comment: solved by the latest `gdata` at least https://github.com/r-gregmisc/gdata/issues/9 and no longer an issue